# linux: monitor logfile for a string and execute script

Tags: linux, bash, script, daemon

I want to monitor a logfile (syslog) on my linux debian box. So if there is a new entry with a secific string, i want to execute a script.

The strings are "alarm start" and "alarm end"

So it should be looking like this (no program language, just my slang;-)):

```
if logfile has changed
get last line (or all new lines)
search for string
if string = "alarm start" found then /foo/bar/script_alarm_start.sh
if string = "alarm end" found then /foo/bar/script_alarm_end.sh
```

Is there something like a daemon that i could use?

Logfile looks like this:

```
Jul  7 06:38:17  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 898051 - Opening new event 14, alarm start]
Jul  7 06:38:23  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 898056 - Gone into alert state]
Jul  7 06:38:31  zmc_m1[8047]: INF [DoorCam: 900000 - Capturing at 25.00 fps]
Jul  7 06:38:33  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 898116 - Left alarm state (14) - 125(5) images]
Jul  7 06:38:33  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 898116 - Closing event 14, alarm end]
...
Jul  7 06:40:38  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 901286 - Opening new event 15, alarm start]
Jul  7 06:40:44  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 901289 - Gone into alert state]
Jul  7 06:40:53  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 901349 - Left alarm state (15) - 123(3) images]
Jul  7 06:40:53  zma_m1[8075]: INF [DoorCam: 901349 - Closing event 15, alarm end]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at [**this thread** at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331309/shellscript-to-monitor-a-log-file-if-keyword-triggers-then-execute-a-command)

Comment: @Groxxda Great solution!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function fs { ls -l LOGFILE | awk '{print $5}' }
function lc { wc -l LOGFILE | awk '{print $1}' }
function sv { fileSize=$(fs) fileLength=$(lc)  }
function ov { nFileSize=$(fs) nFileLeng=$(fs)  }
sv
while true; do
    ov
    if [[ $nFileSize != $fileSize ]]; then
        newLines=$(tail -n $(($nFileLeng-$fileLength)))
        if [[ $(echo "$newLines" | grep "alarm start") ]]; then
            /foo/bar/script_alarm_start.sh
        elif [[ $(echo "$newLines" | grep "alarm end") ]]; then
            /foo/bar/script_alarm_end.sh
        fi
    fi
    sv
done
```

Change LOGFILE to the location of your log file